# Group similar data from multiple tables and add result

Tags: php, mysqli, sum, average

I want to be able to show the number of items the client has and the total for them, and add the prices for each itemid and total price. I am not able to workout the logic for how to do that. So far i can show all the items a client has but some of the items are repeated.

```
$clientid = 24;

$query = "SELECT items.itemid, prices.priceid FROM items 
JOIN prices ON items.itemid = prices.itemid 
WHERE items.clientid = '$clientid'";


$result =  $db_connect -> query($query);
$row_cnt = $result -> num_rows; 

echo $joinrow_cnt."<br/><br/><br/>";

while($assocresult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $price = $assocresult['priceid'];
    $item = $assocresult['itemid'];
    $realprice = ($price/100)*80;        //after 80% discount
    echo "ItemId: ".$item." Price : " .$price." real price: " .$realprice."<br/>";  
}
```

So far i get :

```
ItemId: 1 Price : 100 real price: 80
ItemId: 3 Price : 25 real price: 20
ItemId: 1 Price : 100 real price: 80
ItemId: 5 Price : 200 real price: 160
ItemId: 3 Price : 25 real price: 20
ItemId: 1 Price : 100 real price: 80
```

See how ItemId 1 and 3 are repeated. There are many such rows where the item ids are repeated.

I want the output to be like :

```
ItemId: 1x3 Price: 100 real price = 80x3=240
ItemId: 3x2 Price: 25 real price = 20x2=50
ItemId: 5   Price: 200 real price: 160 //since this item is listed only once.
```

Please help. Many thanks!!

Comment: `sum(prices.priceid)` and group by `items.itemid` also `count(items.itemid)` if you want to count the repetetions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch all `items` and `prices` data and match them up with `WHERE`, then use `GROUP BY` to collect duplicates as one row. With `COUNT(..)` you can get the row count for each item.

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(items.itemid) as cnt,
    items.itemid,
    prices.priceid
FROM items, prices
WHERE 
    items.itemid = prices.itemid
AND
    items.clientid = '$clientid'
GROUP BY items.itemid
```

Comment: I am sorry, I attempted this query but its not giving any results.
I get error: Trying to get property of non-object in .... on line 10

Line 10: 

    $row_cnt = $result -> num_rows;

My quey is : 

`code`
    $myquery = "SELECT
    COUNT(items.itemid) as cnt,
    items.itemid,
    prices.priceid
FROM items, prices
WHERE 
    items.itemid = prices.itemid
AND
    items.clientid = '$clientid'
GROUP BY items.itemid";

$result =  $db_connect -> query($myquery);
 
$row_cnt = $result -> num_rows; 

echo $row_cnt;`code`

What am i doing wrong please.

Thanks a ton for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Check the solution as below:

```
$clientid = 24;

$query = "SELECT items.itemid, prices.priceid, count(items.itemid) as itemcnt FROM items
JOIN prices ON items.itemid = prices.itemid 
WHERE items.clientid = '$clientid' group by items.itemid";


$result =  $db_connect -> query($query);
$row_cnt = $result -> num_rows; 

echo $row_cnt."<br/><br/><br/>";

while($assocresult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$price = $assocresult['priceid'];
$item = $assocresult['itemid'];
$itemcnt = $assocresult['itemcnt'];
$realprice = ($price/100)*80;        //after 80% discount
echo "ItemId: ".$item."x".$itemcnt." Price: " .$price." real price = " .$realprice."x".$itemcnt."=".($realprice*$itemcnt)."<br/>";
}
```

I am not getting any error as you are getting on Line 10. What is the value of `$db_connect` in your code?

Let me know. Thank You!

Comment: Thanks .. For number of rows .. i needed to use $assoc['itemcnt'];